# How to make random number generator not repeat the same number more than twice vb?

Tags: vb.net

so I did a memory game which works perfectly well, except for one thing: there are too many duplicates! I'm trying to have a max of 2 image repeating. Thing is all the code I tried (such as the following) makes every picturebox contain the same image instead of having different ones. I tried making a list as suggested but the result was the same. What am I doing wrong?

```
  Dim generator As New Random
  Dim random As Integer
    Dim picks As New List(Of Integer)
    Dim RndImage(9) As Image

Public Sub btn1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn1.Click

    RndImage(1) = My.Resources.image1
    RndImage(2) = My.Resources.image2
    RndImage(3) = My.Resources.image3
    RndImage(4) = My.Resources.image4
    RndImage(5) = My.Resources.image5
    RndImage(6) = My.Resources.image6
    RndImage(7) = My.Resources.image7
    RndImage(8) = My.Resources.image8
    RndImage(9) = My.Resources.image9

     Do
        random = generator.Next(1, 9)
        If picks.Contains(random) = False Then
            picks.Add(random)
        End If
    Loop Until picks.Count = 18

     PictureBox1.Image = RndImage(random)
    PictureBox2.Image = RndImage(random)
    PictureBox3.Image = RndImage(random)
    PictureBox4.Image = RndImage(random)
    PictureBox5.Image = RndImage(random)
    '...
    PictureBox18.Image = RndImage(random)
End Sub
```

Comment: Make a list or similar with numbers you want (1-9 for example). Then use random to give you an index to remove from the items list. That way you can control duplicates easily. (remember to modify the random as items in the list are removed to not get out of index exceptions)

Comment: It sounds like you don't want a random list.  It sounds like you want a *specific* list that's simply been shuffled.  That's a very different thing.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that! Thanks for your quick reply!

Comment: Plutonix, I saw the link you suggested and tried the code but, for some reason, it only makes all of my picturebox contain the same image.

Comment: Do you know how to make it work because it doesn't generate 9 unique random numbers...@Plutonix

Comment: `Dim picks = Enumerable.Range(1, 9).OrderBy(Function(r) RNG.Next).ToArray()` will give you 9 unique values in random order; the title says no repeats more than 2, which is not what that code does.  Your code is not using the `picks` it created; it is using the last `random` value over and over and over.  Easy to see in the debugger

Comment: But after making the change, it says at 'If picks.Contains(random) = False'
 Public member 'Contains' on type 'Integer()' not found..@Plutonix

Comment: `Dim img = Enumerable.Range(1, 18).OrderBy(Function(r) random.Next()).ToArray()` and then for each image: `PictureBox1.Image = RndImage(img(0)): PictureBox2.Image = RndImage(img(1)): PictureBox3.Image = RndImage(img(2)) ... `

Comment: It worked!!! Thank you very much SkyMaster!! And thanks to everyone who tried to help! ^.^